# Should I use "in" or "on"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which is the correct form in this sentence: "in" or "on"?

> "I'm sending you the requested permission for using my photographs in/on your project"

Comment: Can you please include only one question per post? This way you'll get two great answers for each of your questions.

Comment: Where are you trying to use 'attach'?

Answer (score 5):

***In* vs. *on***: Although there is use for [both forms](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=on+your+project%2C+in+your+project&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), it sounds better to say "in your project". That is, your photographs are becoming a part of this project, so they are *in* it rather than *on* it. There is no hard and fast rule on this, however. You can say:

> I am in choir.
>
> I am on the Executive Board.

Answer (score 0):

"***In*** your project" sounds correct to me.