# "In the wiki" or "on the wiki"

Tags: prepositions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use “in” or “on”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39482/should-i-use-in-or-on)

What is the difference between these two phrases? Which is more common?

> find something **in** the wiki
>
> find something **on** the wiki

Comment: Honestly, I hear both as equally acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

I lean towards *in* the wiki, but I think that is simply because the usage is more common and has become idiomatic. Whether we look "in" or "on" a reference derives from our actions towards its physical incarnation, thus

- in the manual
- in the dictionary
- in the catalog
- in the directory

but

- on the agenda
- on the bulletin board
- on the list

***However***, when referring to a specific wiki, I would use *on*. A wiki is a type of website, and websites are almost invariably "on":

- look it up in the wiki
- look it up on Wikipedia
- look it up in Lexis
- look it up on Lexis.com
- look it up on the intranet
- featured on Yelp
- find us on Facebook

Comment: I agree the more "the wiki" is associated with *a specific website* (such as Wikipedia), the more likely it is we will use "on" rather than "in". Overall, "in" seems to always be more common, but that preference definitely seems to lessen as the target gets more specific.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: There, is the difference you are looking for: it's *in the wiki*; but *on Wikipedia*. Notice that in the above examples, *on* goes with proper names/ domain names, for instance.

Comment: @Kris: Let's not forget we're talking about a stylistic tendency here, not some black/white right/wrong. Also note that if you check UK/US usage for, say, [in/on a database](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+a+database%2Con+a+database&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) you'll see the US favours "in" by more than 5:1, but for the UK that preference is less than 3:1.

Answer (score 1):

It is ***in*** the wiki.

Wiki is a community edited knowledge base, *in* which one could find something.

Comment: unless "wiki" refers to the website on which the wiki resides...

Comment: I don't see why grammatically speaking *the wiki* should be any different to *the database*. Whilst it's true that *in the database* [is more common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in+the+database%2Con+the+database&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), that doesn't imply "on" is in any way "incorrect".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: please see my comment under choster's post.