# *In* or *On* Contacts?

Tags: prepositions, in-on

I'm making a chat application and when the user chooses to delete someone I need to show a confirmation window, but I'm unsure which to use.

Option 1

> Are you sure you want to delete? You will no longer see this person in your Contacts.

Option 2

> Are you sure you want to delete? You will no longer see this person on your Contacts.

Is one more correct or more often used than the other?

Comment: My vote is for "IN."  Contacts in this case acts as a container that contains many individuals.  I have never heard a sentence like this constructed with "ON" rather than "IN."  For context, I am native American English speaker in the northeast United States.

Comment: Really that sounds like a contextual question based on your implementations and preferences. Either works just fine. What makes the most sense to you?  I have people IN my contacts. I have people ON my contacts list

Comment: There is a question which is often cited as a duplicate: [Should I use "in" or "on"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39482/should-i-use-in-or-on). The answer depends on how you visualise *your Contacts:* as a container/group/collection, or a list.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yeah that's what I was *trying* to say

Comment: @MegaMark I concur.  I have heard the usage you shared as well.  However, without the word "list," the sentence would be awkward to my ears.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I use "in" or "on"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-in-or-on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*In your Contacts*" sounds like it would be more appropriate. Since your contacts are a group of people and this person will not longer be *in* that group.

I feel this is somewhat similar to when deciding whether you "Sign in/on" or "Log in/on". It seems like the more acceptable approach is the word "*in*" for the reason that you are dealing with a collection of objects.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of "Contacts" on the internet works a lot like a physical address book and has many of the same expressions.

So someone would be *in* your contacts, since information shared by books is said to be *in* a book.

However, if you change that to "contact list," then it becomes *on*.

"Did you find Brad in your contacts?"

"No, he wasn't on my contact list."